# Conditional concatenate in Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, conditional-statements

I have to concatenate the data in D1 from column A1, B1, C1.

But as per below example if A1 is empty, it should fetch the first not blank data in column A, i.e., A3 and than concatenate D1 = (A3, B1, C1).

Like that for D7 = (A8, B7, C7) and D13 = (A15, B13, C13) so on

For example (underscore indicates empty cell):

Sheet 1

```
   A   B   C    D
1   _  22  11       
2   _  32  21       
3   B  56  89       
4   _  65  90
5   C  22  11       
6   _  32  21       
7   _  56  89       
8   D  65  90       
9   _  32  21       
10  E  56  89       
11  _  65  90
12  F  22  11       
13  _  32  21       
14  _  56  89       
15  G  65  90        
.                  
.                  
.
```

Resulting Sheet 1

```
    A  B   C   D
1   _  22  11  B2211     
2   _  32  21  B3221     
3   B  56  89  B5689     
4   _  65  90  C6590
5   C  22  11  C2211     
6   _  32  21  D3221     
7   _  56  89  D5689     
8   D  65  90  D6590     
9   _  32  21  E3221     
10  E  56  89  E5689     
11  _  65  90  F6590
12  F  22  11  F2211     
13  _  32  21  G3221     
14  _  56  89  G5689     
15  G  65  90  G6590
```

So, your thoughts would be appreciated, and your code welcome!

Comment: This seems like a specification list followed by a code request rather than a question. That isn't how Stack Overflow works. Please describe your efforts in solving your problem and asked a focused question related to those efforts.

Comment: Just trying to do it in excel or VBA an option as well?

Comment: Try this formula `=IF(A1="-",LEFT(D2),A1)&B1&C1` Put it in `D1` cell then drag and down.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this very easy.

1. add the following to cell d1:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP("*",A1:$A$15,1,FALSE)&B1&C1
   ```
2. copy it to the other cells by using the fill handle

### [image]

If you can't remove the underscores try @harun24hr comment, it also works (don't forget to use the fill handle after writing the formula, prior to that it will not output what you want)

Comment: not sure why the downvote, please elaborate as it works

Comment: Do you test the formula? Is it comes output mentioned in the post.

Comment: Yes I tested, added a screenshot for proof

Comment: Do you notice, there is `- (hyphen) ` in `Column A` Your formula will works when they are blank cells.

Comment: The OP explained if the cell is empty, so I removed the hyphen as the OP probably added the hyphen for formatting purposes. I will update my answer to add the hyphen

Answer (score 0):

Please try in D1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),LEFT(D2),A1)&B1&C1
```